# Regex to match only last segment of a folder structure

Tags: regex

I have a recursive list of folders that I need to find characters in, but I do not want subfolders included in the result. I need to find many different characters that will be an issue when migrating data, including asterisks, double periods, etc.

For this example I will use double-period (..). I only need the first, fourth, and seventh lines

```
/System/Modules/Aspect/dmc_attachments_aspect..J5_D65
/System/Modules/Aspect/dmc_attachments_aspect..J5_D65/External Interfaces
/System/Modules/Aspect/dmc_attachments_aspect..J5_D65/Miscellaneous
/System/Modules/Collaboration/com.documentum.services.collaboration.IAttachmentsManager..J5_D65
/System/Modules/Collaboration/com.documentum.services.collaboration.IAttachmentsManager..J5_D65/External Interfaces
/System/Modules/Collaboration/com.documentum.services.collaboration.IAttachmentsManager..J5_D65/Miscellaneous
/System/Modules/TBO/dm_message_archive..J5_D65
/System/Modules/TBO/dm_message_archive..J5_D65/External Interfaces
```

Another example would be an asterisk -- I only need the first, fourth, and seventh lines.

```
/Public/Test/*Training
/Public/Test/*Training*/Documentation
/Public/Test/*Training*/SOPs
/Public/Test/Project**Tracking
/Public/Test/Project**Tracking/01
/Public/Test/Project**Tracking/02
/Public/Home*
/Public/Home*/Test
```

Is there a regex I could use to meet this? I am happy running multiple queries/reports and updating the main character (.. or *)

---

I wanted to give some clarity on the issue so I can avoid the XY problem.

We are migrating data from Documentum to SharePoint, and Documentum does not have  the same file and folder name restrictions, so we will have to address those ahead of the migration or on the fly. I have a big text file (950k lines) containing all of the folders currently in Documentum, and I am attempting to find all folders that will not migrate due to containing these characters.

The issue is that doing a basic `egrep '\*'` will give not just the top level folder containing this character but all subfolders, which will throw off counts.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but what distinguishes the first, fourth, and seventh lines from the others?

Comment: I wouldn't judge you if you did!

They contain subfolders, which would throw off my counts. The goal is to find a list of folders with invalid characters and remove or update them prior to migration. If I included them, it would seem like I had 8 folders to correct, when in reality it is only 3.

Comment: Also if I can reword my question to make it more clear please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you were looking for the double period:

```
.*\.\.[^/]*$
```

would match two periods followed by an unlimited number of non-slash characters until the end of the string. In general, replace `\.\.` with whatever you are looking for.

Check it out at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pD1yG9/1). (Asterisk version [here](https://regex101.com/r/pD1yG9/2)).